# Way to use MySQL for SQL-Fullstack-Generator?

Tags: mysql, node.js, sequelize.js, yeoman-generator

Do I absolutely need to use Postgres for an app that comes out the SQL full-stack generator? Even when I choose MySQL from the console when the generator asks for the data, it causes this error when I run "grunt serve'

```
my-new-project/node_modules/sequelize/lib/sequelize.js:182
    throw new Error('The dialect ' + this.getDialect() + ' is not supported. (
          ^ Error: The dialect postgres is not supported. (Error: Cannot find module 'pg-hstore')
    at new Sequelize (/Users/TerryBu/Desktop/Nestle Related/my-new-project/node_modules/sequelize/lib/sequelize.js:182:11)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/Users/TerryBu/Desktop/Nestle Related/my-new-project/server/api/index.js:8:17)
    at Module._compile (module.js:460:26)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:478:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:355:32)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:310:12)
    at Module.require (module.js:365:17)
    at require (module.js:384:17)
    at module.exports (/Users/TerryBu/Desktop/Nestle Related/my-new-project/server/routes.js:13:3)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/Users/TerryBu/Desktop/Nestle Related/my-new-project/server/app.js:17:20)
    at Module._compile (module.js:460:26)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:478:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:355:32)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:310:12)
    at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:501:10)
    at startup (node.js:129:16)
```

https://www.npmjs.com/package/generator-sql-fullstack

I'm guessing it's because server/config/environment/development.js is like below, but how do I change it to mysql db that's running in the background?

```
'use strict';

// Development specific configuration
// ==================================
module.exports = {
  // MongoDB connection options
  mongo: {
    uri: 'mongodb://localhost/mygeneratorproject-dev'
  },

  // Postgres connection options
  postgres: {
    uri: process.env.POSTGRES_URL ||
         'postgres://user:pass@localhost:5432/mygeneratorproject'
  },
  database: 'test',
  username: 'postgres',
  password: 'root',
  seedDB: true
};
```

Answer (score 3):

This module is not ready for primetime. It does not set up the mysql dependency nor populate mysql connector info in the generated files, despite what you pick during install. It defaults to postgres. The git build is also failing for this project. Seems like it was started then abandoned -- the documentation got further than the generator code.